# android DialogFragment with checkbox doesn't work

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have a dialog fragment, with a checkbox of "don't show this again" which I want to use but for some reason it doesn't work, and the dialog keeps on showing no matter what I mark in the check box.

This is my DialogFragment class:

```
 public class DialogConnectFragment extends DialogFragment {   
        private CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Connect Smart Device?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes, Connect!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                        fragManager.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.frameLayout_remote_activity, new CustomizedDeviceListFragment())
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        builder.setView(R.layout.fragment_dialog_connect);

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_connect, null);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Utils.settingsTAG, 0);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                // Store the isChecked to Preference here
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(DONT_SHOW_DIALOG_MSG, isChecked);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

This is my fragment layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dialog_connect_smart_device_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/connectDialogMessage"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dialog_checkbox_connect_smart_device"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    />
```

This is how I decide if to show the fragment:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Utils.settingsTAG, 0);
    boolean dontShowDialog = sharedPref.getBoolean(DONT_SHOW_DIALOG_MSG, false);
    if (!dontShowDialog) {
        FragmentManager fragManager = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
        DialogConnectFragment  dialogConnectSmartDeviceFragment = new DialogConnectFragment ();
        dialogConnectSmartDeviceFragment.show(fragManager, "DialogFrag");
    }
```

looks like I've implemented it correctly, but after many tests, it doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_connect, null);
 checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
         SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Utils.settingsTAG, 0);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            // Store the isChecked to Preference here
            sharedPref.edit()
            .putBoolean(DONT_SHOW_DIALOG_MSG, isChecked);
            .apply();
        }
    });

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    .setTitle("Connect Smart Device?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes, Connect!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                    fragManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameLayout_remote_activity, new CustomizedDeviceListFragment())
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }
            })
    .setView(view)
    .create()
    .show();
}
```